# Jmeter ramp up distribution

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I wanted to try the following scenario in jmeter. I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

Lets say i want to run a test with 40 users for an hour but i want it to run for the below use case:
I want 10 user to ramp up in 0 seconds (start together) and run for  15 mins and keep on running.
After 15 mins i want another 10 users (total user count is 20 now) to do the same (start all tog-other ) and keep on running.

So in the end of this test there will be 40 users running but i want the add 10 users every 15 mins and have them run till the end of my duration.

How can i achieve this in jmeter? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be to use Ultimate Thread Group.
You can download it here
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/

The link bellow should give you an understanding of how to use the Ultimate Thread Group.
http://www.testingjournals.com/ultimate-thread-group-jmeter/

Comment: Thanks that was the fix.